# zoneminder - fewer events, longer duration?

Tags: webcam

I've got zoneminder 1.25 installed on 12.04 LTS 64 bit, and it's working fine, but seems to capure many events (modect, idle setting) with short durations.  Some captures are only seconds apart, and when I watch an event, I don't see the person walk all the way through the room, sometimes it stops with them partway through.

How can I make the event captures longer (so there are fewer of them, but they catch everything).

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot.
I set the buffer to 200 (25fps * 8 sec) and it made it much better

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer here and other places:  https://zoneminder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide/definemonitor.html#buffers-tab

**Pre/Post Event Image Buffer:

> These options determine how many frames from before and after an event should be preserved with it. This allows you to view what happened immediately prior and subsequent to the event. A value of 10 for both of these will get you started but if you get a lot of short events and would prefer them to run together to form fewer longer ones then increase the Post Event buffer size.

Will implement it and see how well it does...